# Return to previous activity after confirming dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, service

When I click on the back button, I want to close the connection in service and go back to previous activity.

Code in second activity:

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(mBound){
            val dialog = ConfirmDialog()
            dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "confirm")
            //should wait here until "yes" button is pressed and if so, run the code

            mService.closeConnection()
            finish()
        }
        return false
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

When the dialog opens the code continues and closes the connection and goes back to previous activity. I want to wait until I click the "yes" button and then continue code below. I know I should have the code inside dialog, but I can't bind the service to the dialog, so I can't stop the connection from there.
Dialog:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
    builder.setView(view)
        .setTitle("Confirm")
        .setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
        .setNegativeButton("no", DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            //TODO
        })
        .setPositiveButton("yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            //TODO
        })
    return builder.create()
}
```

Again, what I want is simple, when clicking the back button, I can confirm or decline, if I confirm, close the connection in service and go back to previous activity. I guess there is an easier way to do this

Answer (score 0):

I believe your ConfirmDialog() function returns an AlertDialog in which case you can access the components of your alerdialog view this way and close the connection on button click:

```
dialog.(your_yes_button_id).setOnClickListener { 
        
}
```

the above code should go below the following:

```
dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "confirm")
```

Comment: How do I access the button (what is it's id)?

Comment: the id is the same button id in the xml file you have inflated into "view" set for the AlertDialog. As I have mentioned in the answer, you have to access the button id through your instance of AlertDialog so myDialog.myButton.setOnClickListener{}